# Function in trigger - table is mutating error

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm supposed to do a trigger that doesn't allow updating or inserting in the row 'salary' value higher that 30% of average salary for the position(calculated by function). If the value is higher, then the trigger sets up exactly the value (average*130%).
Function to calculate average (it's in a packet - packet1):

```
FUNCTION AVG_SALARY(POSITION POSITIONS.NAME%TYPE)RETURN NUMBER IS 
    AVRG NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT AVG(S.SALARY) INTO AVRG
    FROM STAFF S, POSITIONS P
    WHERE S.ID_POSITION=P.ID_POSITION AND P.NAME=POSITION
    GROUP BY P.NAME;
END;
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER1
BEFORE UPDATE OF SALARY
OR INSERT 
ON STAFF
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    POS POSITIONS.NAME%TYPE;
    AVRG2 NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT NAME INTO POS
    FROM POSITIONS
    WHERE ID_POSITION= :NEW.ID_POSITION ;
    AVRG2 := PACKET1.AVG_SALARY(POS);
    IF :NEW.SALARY > AVRG2*1.3 THEN
        :NEW.SALARY := AVRG2*1.3;
    END IF;
END;
```

I get the error that the table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it.
Please, help

Comment: Who is asking you to do this? The project itself is nonsensical (more on that below); is this a school project? If so, can you (do you have the ability to) abandon this course and take a better one? Why this is nonsensical: suppose you have 100 employees already, and must add three more. Do you add them one by one? Which salaries will be affected will depend on the ORDER in which you add them; the absolute opposite of "set based" processing, the heart of relational databases. Or do you add them all at once? What if in the same transaction you delete an employee; do you insert first?

Comment: Or do you delete first? The salaries will be affected differently depending on what you do first. The "managerial problem" (expressed in plain English regardless of SQL, triggers and mutating tables) makes no sense to begin with.

Comment: Yes, this is for my school project. Information about employees was in .txt file and we had to put those information into tables like: staff, positions, etc. New employees would be added all at once. I see you point on that the salary will depend on the adding order. But is there a way to put into a variable the average salary before adding the new employee to compare that value to the new.salary?

Comment: since it is for a school project, I won't give it all away, but you can use a combination of triggers to do it.  You will need a before update trigger that is statement level, then a for every row trigger that will just capture the rows that changed, then you will need an after update trigger that is statement level that will do the update for you.